# luigi: command-line parameters not becoming part of a task's signature?

Tags: command-line, parameters, luigi

In luigi, I know how to use its parameter mechanism to pass command-line parameters into a task. However, if I do so, the parameter becomes part of the task's signature.

But there are some cases -- for example, if I want to optionally pass a `--debug` or `--verbose` flag on the command line -- where I don't want the command-line parameter to become part of the task's signature.

I know I can do this outside of the luigi world, such as by running my tasks via a wrapper script which can optionally set environment variables to be read within my luigi code. However, is there a way I can accomplish this via luigi, directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just declare them as [insignificant parameters](http://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parameters.html#insignificant-parameters), ie instantiate the parameter class passing `significant=False` as keyword argument.

Example:

```
class MyTask(DateTask):
    other = luigi.Parameter(significant=False)
```

Comment: That's exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you.